# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Speech.dll

Tags: c#, speech

im googling now since hours but dont get it whats wrong there

Error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Speech.dll
```

Additional information: Double-quoted string not valid.

Image where it happens e.t.c.
[I had first the double quotes error which got fixed with removing the " ' ", if i comment out the lowest 2 lines (create grammar and loading) its working, but logically not loading it... "name" is a List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vVxD.png)

Comment: You're running a release build, the debugger is pointing to the wrong line. The culprit is your `name` array. Inspect it.

Comment: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Speech.dll

Additional information: Double-quoted string not valid.`

Error in

`Grammar steamGames = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(name.ToArray())));`

But i dont have any double quotes in it...

Comment: Cannot edit again so --- Edit xD

It has " ' " in it... which i can't remove since i dont know how, a for loop isnt working, replacing it in the result string neither (like i did)

Comment: Edit Edit --- i changed the json to list thing now like that: `name = json.applist.apps.Select(p => p.name.Replace("'","")).ToList();` this removes all the " ' " but i still get the error

Heres the JSON data which im getting: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2

Comment: That was because `string.Replace()` returns a new string, which you didn't assign to anything. It would've worked with `result = result.Replace(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with `name = json.applist.apps.Select(p => p.name.Replace("\"", string.Empty)).ToList();`